Control when a light starts blinking?
I want to animate a blinking light controlled by keyframes, however, I only want the action to start at a certain driver value controlled by a an object’s position - so if I had multiples of the light and object, the light blinking could be turned on at different rates. Is there a way to do this, or an alternative way to get the same effect?

You could have a light permanently blinking, but multiply the strength by 0 when it should not blink and 1 when it should. This multiplier could be driven by an object's position.

Let say, I have an empty with animated Z-position that blinks from 1 to 0:

And also I have a Cube, that should control then effect should start, by animating Z-position of it:

So I select the lamp and add driver to Power value:

Here that you should do in driver settings. Set type to scripted expression and expression  should be
cube * noise * 4000

where:
cube is the value of transform channel Z-position of the cube
noise is the value of transform channel Z-position of the empty
4000 is the power of the light source

i edited your "nose" - hope that's ok
